# Defining an 'HttpClient' singleton via StructureMap causes an error about 'HttpMessageHandler' being not configured in runtime

Tags: c#, rest, dependency-injection, structuremap, dotnet-httpclient

Trying to define an HttpClient singleton in StructureMap ala:

```
For<HttpClient>().Singleton().UseIfNone<HttpClient>();
```

This results in the following error in runtime (upon dependency injection):

```
   StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler'

   There is no configuration specified for System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler

   1.) new HttpClient(*Default of HttpMessageHandler*)
   2.) System.Net.Http.HttpClient
   3.) Instance of System.Net.Http.HttpClient
   4.) new AdmanAdapter(*Default of HttpClient*)
   5.) Organotiki.vNext.PostEval.Data.Adapters.ADMAN.AdmanAdapter
   6.) Instance of [....]

      at lambda_method(Closure , IBuildSession , IContext )
      at StructureMap.Building.BuildPlan.Build(IBuildSession session, IContext context)
      at StructureMap.BuildSession.BuildNewInSession(Type pluginType, Instance instance)
      at StructureMap.Pipeline.NulloTransientCache.Get(Type pluginType, Instance instance, IBuildSession session)
      at StructureMap.BuildSession.ResolveFromLifecycle(Type pluginType, Instance instance)
      at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance, ILifecycle lifecycle)
```

If we also configure HttpMessageHandler like so:

```
For<HttpClient>().Singleton().UseIfNone<HttpClient>();
For<HttpMessageHandler>().UseIfNone(x => new HttpClientHandler());
```

Then the problem goes away. The question is why? The default constructor for HttpClient takes care of its own dependency injection:

```
/// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Net.Http.HttpClient" /> class.</summary>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public HttpClient()
  : this((HttpMessageHandler) new HttpClientHandler())
{
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The container does not use the default constructor by default. It uses the constructor with the most dependencies if multiple constructors are found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From structuremap docs at http://structuremap.github.io/registration/constructor-selection

> If there are multiple public constructor functions on a concrete
>   class, StructureMap's default behavior is to select the "greediest"
>   constructor, i.e., the constructor function with the most parameters.

If you look at the possible constructors for `HttpClient`, it should be

```
public HttpClient();
public HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler);
public HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler, bool disposeHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Just one more question: If I use "For<HttpClient>().Singleton().UseIfNone(x => new HttpClient());" I still get the same error despite the fact that I have specified the constructor explicitly. What gives?

Comment: @XDS That doesn't look correct. You are explicitly saying, "for this *concrete* class, use a single instance of it. If no concrete instance is found, then use this lambda/constructor logic". `HttpClient` is a concrete class, so structuremap is *always* able to "attempt" to create an instance of it. If it was an interface for example, `IFoo`, then it would resort to using your lamdba expression to get an instance. As it is now, it just completely ignores your `UseIfNone`.

Comment: I guess I have to subclass HttpClient then decorate the subclass with an interface and then configure that one instead. What a strange trip this will be. Thanks btw. I could have never figured all these subtleties on my own. Thumbs up mate.

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to the following... `For<HttpClient>().Singleton().Use(x => new HttpClient())`. Here you are explicitly telling structuremap "This is exactly how I want the `HttpClient` instance to be created"

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Brad M's answer, what worked for me is `.SelectConstructor(() => new HttpClient())`. Specifying which constructor should be used explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work:

```
        For<HttpMessageHandler>().UseIfNone(x => new HttpClientHandler());

        var recaptchaHttpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/")
        };
        For<IReCaptchaService>().Use<ReCaptchaService>()
            .SelectConstructor(() => new ReCaptchaService(recaptchaHttpClient));
```